# Looking for a jQuery image slider with a central viewport and

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking for a jQuery image slider which can be set as full width with a central viewport and then the previous and next slides are displayed next to the viewport. Like this:

http://m4tt.co/1B0l3d3c2M2G3t1w1w08

Comment: Link dead as of June 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the third demo on the infinite carousel page (http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/) you'll see that it has a peek option that allows you to show the previous and next images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I created a while ago that matches your question

http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/zKhxz/3/